# Classic ASP server-side JSON library

Tags: javascript, json, asp-classic, legacy

I have inherited some Classic ASP code and I need a JSON library that can be instantiated and run server-side for use with JavaScript-coded server-side ASP.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For writing/outputting JSON i believe the [aspjson](http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/) project is a pretty good choice. Parsing JSON in ASP "classic" is discussed here:

- [Any good libraries for parsing JSON in Classic ASP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019223/any-good-libraries-for-parsing-json-in-classic-asp)

In that thread, Chris Nielsen has a creative idea of using a Javascript library on the server side (as ASP supports JScript as well as VBScript). I have not tried it, but maybe that could solve both parsing and writing.

Comment: The QueryToJSON function is pretty great. 1 line to output a database result as json!

Answer (score 9):

In my experience, 
[JSON2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) works in Classic ASP.

To use it, I do this in the .asp code:

```
<%@ language="Javascript" %>

<script language="javascript" runat="server" src='json2.js'></script>

<script language="javascript" runat="server">

   ... my code here....

   // use the JSON object:
   var jsonRepresentation = JSON.stringify(myObject, null, 2);

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used aspjson with great success.

http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/

Answer (score 1):

You could try something similar to this: http://www.lshift.net/blog/2005/10/11/simple-ajax-with-json-chat-application-for-asp-30

It has a fairly direct encapsulation of the old json.js into a json.asp file for running on the server-side.