# How to return a JSON object in classic ASP

Tags: ajax, json, asp-classic

I want to return a JSON object using a classic ASP script (it's part of an AJAX request).

If I just send the reponse as text like:

```
response.write("{ query:'Li', suggestions:['Liberia','Libyan Arab Jamahiriya','Liechtenstein','Lithuania'], data:['LR','LY','LI','LT'] }")
```

will this work, or do I actually need a JSON library?

**Edit:** I'm trying to get the autocomplete plugin at http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/#howto to work.

javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var a = $('#txtValue').autocomplete({ 
    serviceUrl:'script.asp',
    minChars:2, 
    maxHeight:400,
    width:300,
    zIndex: 9999,
    deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
    onSelect: function(value, data){ alert('You selected: ' + value + ', ' + data); },
});
```

ASP:

```
<% 
response.ContentType = "application/json"
response.write("{ query:'Li', suggestions:['Liberia','Libyan Arab Jamahiriya','Liechtenstein','Lithuania'], data:['LR','LY','LI','LT'] }") 
%>
```

Autocomplete is not working. It works if I use a local lookup array like
    lookup: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May']

But there's something wrong with the ajax meaning it doesn't return the list properly.

Comment: Have you actually tried it? Give it a go, what have you got to lose?

Comment: I tried it, it's not working haha. I'm just not sure if this is the reason or not. I'm trying to get the autocomplete plugin (http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/#howto) working

Comment: I know you already solve your problem, but here is a link to validate your JSON and be sure that is not it that cause the problem:
http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It appears to be a parsing error on the client side.

I didn't think this would make a difference, but it looks like if you quote everything, including the property names, it seems to work. And use double-quotes instead of single quotes - that apparently is making a difference.

Remember to double your double-quotes (at least I think that's how you do it in VBScript - been a long time).

So:

```
<%
    Response.ContentType = "application/json"
    Response.Write("{ ""query"":""Li"", ""suggestions"":[""Liberia"",""Libyan Arab Jamahiriya"",""Liechtenstein"",""Lithuania""], ""data"":[""LR"",""LY"",""LI"",""LT""] }")
%>
```

Comment: I don't see why that wouldn't work. Just make sure you set the content type to "application/json".

Comment: In the documentation for the plugin, it says: "Web page that provides data for Ajax Autocomplete will receive GET request with querystring ?query=Li, and it must return JSON data in the following format" and then gives string in my question. Shouldn't it work for testing if I just response.write it as shown?

Comment: I added response.ContentType = "application/json" but it's still not working :(

Comment: Beat me to it. Yes double your quotes to escape them in vbScript.

Comment: It's not a parsing error.  The [JSON grammar](http://json.org/) specifies that property names are strings, and strings must be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: Use Response.Clear before setting content-type for it to work in IE 8 or under

Answer (score 3):

[Joe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977261/how-to-return-a-json-object-in-classic-asp/6977387#6977387) should work for you. However you might want to look at [aspjson](http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/) if you are going to be outputting a lot of JSON from classic ASP.

Comment: It's also straightforward to use the json2.js script, from Crockford.  https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js   See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/9630663/48082

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work with the code below....
After doubling the quotes and putting in the query string

```
currQuery= request.querystring("query")
response.expires=-1
Dim rsMain,sqlMain,rettxt,JobOpenToArr
set rsMain= Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsMain.CursorLocation = adUseClient
sqlMain = "select JobOpenTo FROM Jobs WHERE JobOpenTo LIKE '%"&currQuery & "%' group by JobOpenTo order by JobOpenTo" 
rsMain.Open sqlMain, Session("XXX_CMS")
if Not rsMain.Eof  Then   
              '## build the string
       rettxt = "{query:""" & currQuery & """, suggestions:["

     JobOpenToArr = rsMain.getRows()     
     For i = 0 to UBound(JobOpenToArr,2)

       rettxt = rettxt & """" & JobOpenToArr(0,i) & ""","

     Next    
     '##knock off trailing comma
     rettxt = left(rettxt,len(rettxt)-1)
     rettxt = rettxt & "]}"
     Response.Write rettxt
```