# Setting up multi-dimensional array in VBScript

Tags: php, asp-classic, vbscript

I am converting a php program over to VBScript for ASP. I am stuck trying to find a way to structure a multi-dimensional array and could use some help.

Here is how it sets up in the php version:

```
// $_SESSION[model name][level name][menu name] => [state]
$_SESSION[$model] = array('level_name' => array('menu_name' => array()));
```

and then here is how I set a value later on

```
$_SESSION[$model][$level_name][$menu_name] = array('menu_state' => 'UNCHECKED');
```

Here is what I tried in VBScript that doesn't work

```
Session(model).Add "level_name", Array()
Session(model)("level_name").Add "menu_name", Array()
Session(model)("level_name")("menu_name").Add "menu_state", Array()
```

and then try to set the value

```
Session(model)(level_name)(menu_name)("menu_state") = "UNCHECKED"
```

but I end up with the very helpful 500 Server Error.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would try using JSON.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019223/any-good-libraries-for-parsing-json-in-classic-asp

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292575/classic-asp-server-side-json-library

Comment: No thanks. It's hard enough learning one new thing, adding in another would make it even harder.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Dictionary of Dictionaries:

```
  Dim dicX : Set dicX = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Set dicX("A") = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Set dicX("A")("B") = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Set dicX("A")("B")("C") = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  dicX("A")("B")("C")("D") = "WhatEver"
  WScript.Echo dicX("A")("B")("C")("D")
```

Comment: Thank You, that's what I'll go with.