# create Plist in .net from list of objects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an iPad app that is fed data via web service returning JSON.  Watching some iTunes U episodes, it looks like sending back Plist would save me a ton of time and speed up my app quite a bit on the parsing side of things.

Does anyone know of a .net library that converts objects into this Plist to return instead?

EDIT (this is my very limited understanding of this topic):
An Plist is a Property List that iOS can use to easily encode and/or parse data. It is very similar to JSON except parsing takes a fraction of the time and can be done in 1 line of code.  If your server uses WebObjects then encoding can also be done in 1 line of code, I am using IIS so I need a solution for this if one exists before I write my own.

You can see the videos here:
http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

In particular watch Session 117 - Building a Server-Driven User Experience

Comment: Could you explain what an *ASCII Plist* is for those who haven't watched the episodes that you haven't linked to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may checkout [this project](http://plistdotnet.sourceforge.net/). Sample usage:

```
object value = ...
string plist = Plist.PlistDocument.CreateDocument(value);
```

The only requirement is to decorate your object with [`[Serializable]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) attribute.

Comment: sweet, looks like exactly what I was looking for - have you used this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WebObjects, the appserver from apple, there's a java mirror class of NSPropertyListSerialization that does all of this for you; you can pass it NSArray's, NSDictionaries, etc and it will just work. Not sure if that's what you're talking about; confused as to the WebObjects in your question. HTH's.