# Send to & decode JSON data in a server side method

Tags: asp.net, json, pagemethods

i dont know how to send JSON data to server side function and also i dont know how to de-serialize the JSON data to a particular class.

suppose i need to send customer related info from client side to server side through json and jquery and i want that customer info will be deserialize to my customer class in the server side. please help me code & concept.

Comment: You should try Googling first. http://www.webdevbros.net/2007/04/26/generate-json-from-asp-datatypes/ and http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/ are both JSON decoders

Comment: i search and i got few links but their approach was different. they are sending complex data to client size after converting to json format. so i need a guide which enable me to send complex data from client side to server side and decode there to my class.

Comment: You might look in this similar thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019223/any-good-libraries-for-parsing-json-in-classic-asp

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET will handle [JSON deserializing a page method's parameters automatically](http://encosia.com/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/).

For example, if you have this `Person` class:

```
public class Person {
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
  public string State { get; set; }
  public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

And a page method that accepts a parameter of that type:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void DoSomethingWithPerson(Person ThePerson)
```

If you pass JSON like this into the method:

```
{"ThePerson":{"FirstName":"Dave","LastName":"Ward"}}
```

Then, the ASP.NET will automatically convert the JSON to an instance of the `Person` class and send that into the page method as `ThePerson`.