# ASP Classic: Iterating a json2.js object

Tags: json, asp-classic, vbscript, msxml

I am getting a JSON result in ASP Classic like this:

```
<script language="JScript" runat="server" src="json2.js"></script>
<%
Response.ContentType = "text/html"

Dim HttpReq
Dim Diamond
Set HttpReq = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
HttpReq.open "GET", "http://url.com?id=" & Request.QueryString("id"), False
HttpReq.send

res = HttpReq.responseText
Set res = JSON.parse(res)
%>
```

**It works.**

Let's say the JSON result will look like this:

```
res = {
    gallery: { 
        image1: { img: 'source url', thumb: 'source url' },
        image2: { img: 'source url', thumb: 'source url' },
        image3: { img: 'source url', thumb: 'source url' }
    },
    another_param1: 'foo',
    another param2: 'bar',
    ...
}
```

**I want to then iterate the gallery object, not in JScript, but in VBScript.**

How can I do that?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019223/any-good-libraries-for-parsing-json-in-classic-asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is really necessary to enumerate an object's properties in VBScript then you will need to convert the object to a dictionary.  Here is a simple function that will take a JScript object and return `Scripting.Dictionary`:

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">

    function JScriptObjectToDictionary(o)
    {
        var dict = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        for (var prop in o)
        {
            if (o.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            {
                dict.add(prop, o[prop]);
            }
        }

        return dict;
    }
</script>
```

With this function present in your page you can now convert the `gallery` property to a dictionary:

```
 res.gallery = JScriptObjectToDictionary(res.gallery)
```

You can then iterate as:

```
 For Each key in res.gallery
     Response.Write key & ": " & res.gallery(key).img & "<br />"
 Next
```

Having said that its worth pointing out that properties named as a series like image1, image2 are a poor choice.  It would be better if the JSON defined gallery as a simple array rather than an object.  If you are in a position to influence the JSON design you should require that it be changed.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to change that to an array. Would you mind updating your answer with another snippet according to that? Thank you.

Comment: Why an array? In this case a dictionary is sufficient. Arrays have a fixed dimension, therefor appending an item to an array is inefficient in VBScript.

Comment: Well the JSON "gallery" will have to be implemented as an array anyway, like Anthony says, and then in VBScript it will have to be parsed into a dictionary, like you say Guido.
I don't have any idea how to do that though, and would appreciate a code example a lot :)
Bottom line is I need to iterate this object in VBScript, not JScript. Thanks.

Comment: @Pilau: Do you need a VBScript array or is a JScript array sufficient (you can foreach items in a JScript array).  To get a JScript array change the JSON to something sensable.  If you want a VBScript array is the order of items in the array important?

Comment: I need a VBScript array, thanks - and the order of the items in the gallery is not important. I will just have have to iterate over this list of items in VBScript eventually.

Answer (score 2):

AXE(ASP Xtreme Evolution) JSON parser will do the trick for you.
Just google it.
Once you include AXE in your file;

```
set Info = JSON.parse(RES)
Response.write(Info.gallery & vbNewline)
Response.write(Info.gallery.image & vbNewline)
```

edit---

When you will need to create a loop for the gallery;

dim key : for each key in Info.keys()
    Response.write( key & vbNewline )
next

Comment: Iteration is requested in the question, I see no iteration here?

Comment: AXE has a simple example for that too. I added it in my message.

Comment: Uhm, the example is in general for iterating a dictionary. No need for AXE in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON is simple and always the same structure you can parse it yourself, it's fast and simple an dno need for an external library.

```
res = "{"_
    &"gallery: { "_
    &"    image1: { img: 'source url1', thumb: 'source url1' },"_
    &"    image2: { img: 'source url2', thumb: 'source url2' },"_
    &"    image3: { img: 'source url3', thumb: 'source url3' }"_
    &"},"_
    &"another_param1: 'foo',"_
    &"another param2: 'bar'"_
    &"}"

'convert the JSON string to an array
Set oRegExpre = new RegExp
oRegExpre.Global = true
oRegExpre.Pattern = "{ img.*?}"

'iterate the array (records)
Set records = oRegExpre.Execute(res)
for each record in records
  aRecord = split(record,"'")
  key1 = replace(aRecord(0),"{ ","")
  key2 = replace(aRecord(2),", ","")
  wscript.echo key1 & aRecord(1) 'schow key & value pairs
  wscript.echo key2 & aRecord(3)
next

=>
img: source url1
thumb: source url1
img: source url2
thumb: source url2
img: source url3
thumb: source url3
```

Comment: It's a positive thought but the JSON is subject to change - thanks though