# How to read json from request form in ASP

Tags: json, asp-classic

I want to know how I can read JSON when it comes directly from another server, like a form. I have to request and process JSON.

```
dim datos: set datos = json.parse(BodyJson)
    dim key : for each key in datos.keys() 
        Status = datos.get(key).category 
        FechaHoraEnvio = datos.get(key).date 
        DireccionEmail =  datos.get(key).recipient
        InfoExtra = datos.get(key).tags
        ID= 123
        sSQL = "INSERT INTO EmailsStatus (Id, Status, FechaHoraEnvio, DireccionEmail, InfoExtra) VALUES ('"& ID &"', '"& Status &"', '"& FechaHoraEnvio &"', '"& DireccionEmail &"', '"& InfoExtra &"')"
        Response.write sSql
        objAccessDB.excecuteQuery(sSQL)
    next
```

Comment: Check this previous SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019223/any-good-libraries-for-parsing-json-in-classic-asp

Comment: i prefer json2.asp in the AXE framework

Comment: Cool, I had a look at the json2.asp code on github and it already implements the SO post suggestion to use the Douglas Crockford json2.js library

Comment: Could you specify a bit more what your problem is? Are you having trouble getting the "BodyJson" or trouble getting Status, FechaHoraEnvio, DireccionEmail , InfoExtra ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
dim datos: set datos = json.parse(BodyJson)
dim key : for each key in datos.keys()
    if (key = "category") then Status = datos.get(key)
    if (key="date") then FechaHoraEnvio = datos.get(key)
    if (key = "recipient") then DireccionEmail =  datos.get(key)
    if (key = "tags") then InfoExtra = datos.get(key)
    ID= 123
    sSQL = "INSERT INTO EmailsStatus (Id, Status, FechaHoraEnvio, DireccionEmail, InfoExtra) VALUES ('"& ID &"', '"& Status &"', '"& FechaHoraEnvio &"', '"& DireccionEmail &"', '"& InfoExtra &"')"
    Response.write sSql
    objAccessDB.excecuteQuery(sSQL)
next
```