# Read json response in HP Service test

Tags: json, web-services, qtp

How can i read a Json response in HP Service Test ?

```
 "id" : "1lad07", "text" : "test", "url" : "http:\/\/twitpic.com\/1lacuz", "width" : 220, "height" : 84, "size" : 8722, "type" : "png", "timestamp" : "Wed, 05 May 2010 16:11:48 +0000", "user" : { "id" : 12345, "screen_name" : "twitpicuser" } }
```

i wanted to retrieve the path of id from the below response.

Kindly suggest

Comment: If you show what you´ve tried (no matter how bad you failed), lots of people will try to help. "Kindy suggest" is just the polite form of "Sho me da codez" ;-) also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151600/uft11-50-service-test-how-can-i-obtain-the-data-from-the-response-body, even though the OP there did not ask a much better question :-\