# classic ASP: How to speed up delivering content to client?

Tags: ajax, asp-classic, vbscript

I am maintaining a classic ASP application. It has some reports and few of them has around 25 columns and around 600 rows. I return the data from the server to the client over an AJAX call and display the results.

What I do is I create the HTML string for a table with the header and rows on the server side (using string concatenation) and do a `response.write` at the end.

```
if not rsStatus.eof then
        strresult=strresult & "<table class='sort-table' id='table-1'><thead><tr class='gridHeader' style='height:15px;'>"
        strresult=strresult & "<td>S.N.</td>"
        strresult=strresult & "<td>TSPL Job No.</td>"
        strresult=strresult & "<td>Client Name</td>"
        strresult=strresult & "<td>Job Type</td>"
        strresult=strresult & "<td>Govt Office</td>"
        strresult=strresult & "<td>Ref Value</td>"
        strresult=strresult & "<td>Govt File No.</td>"
        strresult=strresult & "<td>Submission Date</td>"
        strresult=strresult & "<td>Days Elasped Since Filing Date</td>"
        strresult=strresult & "<td>Process-Cycle/Status stage</td>"
        strresult=strresult & "<td>Status/  Remarks</td>"
        strresult=strresult & "<td>Status Last Updated on</td>"
        strresult=strresult & "<td>Trigon Bill No</td>"
        strresult=strresult & "<td>Trigon Bill Date</td>"
        strresult=strresult & "<td>Payment Received / Pending</td>"
        strresult=strresult & "</thead></tr><tbody>"
        dim rownum
        rownum = 1
        while not rsStatus.eof
            strresult=strresult & "<tr class='gridrow " & IIf(rownum Mod 2=1,"bgodd","bgeven") &"'>"
            strresult=strresult & "<td>" & rownum & "</td>"
            strresult=strresult & "<td><a href='http://localhost/app/global/weblets/Jobdetails.asp?JobId=" & rsStatus("iJobId") & "' target='new'>" & rsStatus("vJobNo") & "</a></td>"
            strresult=strresult & "<td>" & rsStatus("Client") & "</td>"
            strresult=strresult & "<td>" & rsStatus("vJobType") & "</td>"
            strresult=strresult & "<td>" & rsStatus("GovtOffice") & "</td>"
            strresult=strresult & "<td>" & rsStatus("RefVal") & "</td>"
            strresult=strresult & "<td>" & rsStatus("FileNo") & "</td>"
            strresult=strresult & "<td>" & rsStatus("SubmitedOn") & "</td>"
            strresult=strresult & "<td>" & rsStatus("elapsed") & "</td>"
            strresult=strresult & "<td>" & rsStatus("CurrentStatus") & "</td>"
            strresult=strresult & "<td>" & rsStatus("comment") & "</td>"
            strresult=strresult & "<td>" & rsStatus("dStatusDate") & "</td>"
            strresult=strresult & "<td>" & rsStatus("BillNo") & "</td>"
            strresult=strresult & "<td>" & rsStatus("BillDate") & "</td>"
            strresult=strresult & "<td>" & rsStatus("PymtStatus") & "</td>"
            strresult=strresult & "</tr>"
            rownum = rownum+1
            rsStatus.movenext
        wend
        strresult=strresult & "</tbody></table>"
    else
        strresult=strresult & "<tr class='gridrow'><td colspan=3>No Status Present for the Job</td></tr>"
    end if
    Response.Write(strresult)
```

The performance is not very good as the no of rows is increasing.

What might be a better way to do it?

Comment: Are you positive that the slow-down is the snippet of code you've shown? Could it be the cursor that fetches the rows? Or client-side script that works on all rows? Also, if you're returning all this in an AJAX call, why don't you move all the markup to the client page/HTML, return just the data (in JSON)?

Comment: @G.Stoynev: I was looking for suggestion that you are proposing. But, I wanted to understand if JSON will speed up the response. I know, the table structure might also delay the rendering on the client side. I have observed that the SQL server behind returns the data much earlier, but the client keep waiting for the entire data. In JSON, i need to send the field name with every value, whereas in this I am sending the values only.

Comment: In fact in JSON you won't be sending the field name, nor the markup, so it'll be less than the current string length. Plus you'll spare all the concatenations, which @MaxiWheat points out as a slow-down factor.

Comment: Thanks @G.Stoynev. Any clue how I may be able to send JSON from the server side using classic ASP?

Comment: You need to prepare JSON-formatted string and Response.Write it to the client. There are many libraries that help with the formatting - see my answer to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689469/web-services-classic-asp/15696891#15696891)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to add an answer to my own question here as this gave me a good performance enhancement.

I converted my SQL queries to `for xml` queries with every column as 'td' like this:

```
Select col1 as [td], col2 as [td], col3 as [td] from table for xmpl path('tr'), root('table')
```

and returned the result back to the browser with almost no handling on the ASP server side code.

Answer (score 2):

String concatenation in VBScript has really poor performance, you could try to improve your script using methods described in [those](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/tutorials/article.php/c19367/VBScript-String-Concatenation-And-Why-It-Should-Be-Avoided-Like-The-Plague.htm) [articles](https://web.archive.org/web/20210324003446/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092500-1.shtml).

The most simple case is to create an array with all the strings in it, and then call `Join` to concatenate them all.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

No need to build up a string, just write out the lines.

e.g.

```
<% if not rsStatus.eof then %>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>S.N.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<% end if %>
```