# call regular asp from javascript in other domain

Tags: javascript, dom, asp-classic, dojo, cross-domain

I have used `dojo/dom` from a `javascript` file before to call a `php` file on another domain that handles some database queries and returns the result to the javascript file.

The call to the php file was (i offcourse hope i can use the same call to asp)

```
postdata = dojo.toJson({ action: "get",  userid: 1 });
require(["dojo/_base/xhr", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"],
function (xhr, dom) {
var xhrArgs = {
    url: "http://otherdomain.com/file.php",
    postData: postdata,
    handleAs: "text",
    load: function (result) { }
};
var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
```

In the php file i had

```
$foo = file_get_contents("php://input");
$postvalue = json_decode($foo, true);
```

to read the values from the `dom` call.

The reason i need to do this is because i get an error from the browser about a security risk because of the cross domain request.

So i think i need to use Jsonp

How do I write the php code in asp? **NOT asp.net**

Comment: i have also tried using $.ajax but i causes an mime type mismatch and i cant find any information about this exact situation where a javascript file calls a classic asp file and gets a mime type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Since your post data is JSON, the `Request.Form` won't be filled in, so you will have to use [`Request.BinaryRead`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525710(v=vs.90).aspx) and [convert](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_binarytostring/) this result as a string.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019223/any-good-libraries-for-parsing-json-in-classic-asp) to convert this JSON string into an object.

Comment: My old php code call had alot of parameters including arrays. Thats why i used Json. I dont need to use Json with the asp call.

Comment: edit: i think i need to use Jsonp because of the cross domain security risk request

Comment: In that case you can send your data urlencoded and use [`Request.Form`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx) in ASP to readout each parameter.

Comment: About cross domain, you can set the [access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) http headers to allow another domain to access it

Comment: I have tried the access control headers but cant get it to work in regular asp :(
Please show me the lines if you have them :)

Comment: To give public access to all domains: `Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` `Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");`

Comment: Strangely enough those lines fail.
Firstly ; at the end of just one line causes the file to fail completely.
The () also causes the file to fail
If i change 
    Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
to
    Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"
it doesnt fail but it also doesnt work

Comment: Oh yeah my was code was in jscript, but you're using vbscript, so it should be indeed `Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"` and `Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"`

Comment: About your mime type mismatch, just add the correct content-type as well: for example `Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/plain"`

Comment: Yes i already changed the syntax to vbscript:
I must admit i have never worked with mine types before since i never had a problem before.
How do i know which mime type is the correct and should it be the first line in the ASP file? Should i also have a mime type line in the javascript file that calls the ASP file through AJAX?