# How would I iterate through json array using aspjson with classic asp?

Tags: arrays, json, asp-classic

I've come this far with help from http://www.aspjson.com/ and [Looping through JSON Array using ASPJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30802632/looping-through-json-array-using-aspjson)

```
<!--#include file="aspjson.asp" -->

jsonstring = "{""events"":""[{
""email"":""john@test.com"",
""timestamp"":1461015166,
""smtp-id"":""\u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555\u003e"",
""event"":""processed"",
""category"":""cat facts"",
""sg_event_id"":""Y4SkYnMgWCH-j0Ap2HUBlg=="",
""sg_message_id"":""14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0""
},
{
"email"":""example@test.com"",
""timestamp"":1461015166,
""smtp-id"":""\u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555\u003e"",
""event"":""deferred"",
""category"":""cat facts"",
""sg_event_id"":""QVvoFUd9LS5083KTavaqAw=="",
""sg_message_id"":""14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0"",
""response"":""400 try again later"",""attempt"":""5""
},
{
""email"":""john@test.com"",
""timestamp"":1461015166,
""smtp-id"":""\u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555\u003e"",
""event"":""processed"",
""category"":[""Cat Facts"",""Fish Facts""],
""sg_event_id"":""Y4SkYnMgWCH-j0Ap2HUBlg=="",
""sg_message_id"":""14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0""
}]""}"


Set jJSON = New aspJSON
jJSON.loadJSON(jsonstring)

For Each son In jJSON.data("events")
For Each grandson In jJSON.data("events").item(son)
    response.write "<b>" & grandson & ": </b>" & jJSON.data("events").item(son).item(grandson) & "<br>"
Next
response.write "<br>"
Next
```

Most of the examples I've found have the names of the keys but I don't always know what they are.

My problem comes when my loop gets to the last set where the category contains two elements. "Cat Facts" and "Fish Facts".

error message is:
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01c2'
Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

If I could get this working it would be a step in the right direction, but "Categories" could be any name in another record and it could have single or multiple values.

I think I need to add an if/then but I'm stuck here. I think I want to do something like this pseudo code

```
if isarray(grandson) then
for each greatgrandson in grandson
    response.write greatgrandson
else
    response.write "<b>" & grandson & ": </b>" & jJSON.data("events").item(son).item(grandson) & "<br>"
end if
```

I'm sure its evident that I'm still struggling with how all this fits together, so if anyone has any pointers or links to descriptions that might be helpful it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the *grandson* is an object, and if it is loop through it an display:

```vbs
For Each son In jJSON.data("events")
For Each grandson In jJSON.data("events").item(son)
    response.write "<b>" & grandson & ": </b>"
    if NOT isObject(jJSON.data("events").item(son).item(grandson)) then
        response.write jJSON.data("events").item(son).item(grandson) 
    else
        for each category in jJSON.data("events").item(son).item(grandson)
            Response.write jJSON.data("events").item(son).item(grandson)(category) & ","
        next
    end if
    Response.write "<br>"
Next
response.write "<br>"
Next
```

Comment: is it possible by using for loop so that i can get the index.Or any other way to get the index number.

Comment: @rykamol I dont understand, index of what? Maybe you could post a question?

Comment: I want to get array index of grandson (your solution example).

Comment: @rykamol maybe you could use a counter within the for each grandson loop

Comment: That's the way i can achieve my goal.Thank you so much @SearchAndResQ