# Parse json in classic ASP

Tags: json, asp-classic

I'm trying to integrate our ERP-system into our website. I'm able to get some json responce from the system. But I really need some help parsing it.

I'm using ASPJSON (www.aspjson.com) to help me.

The question is how do I get all the fields from "Data". I'm able to get the DebtorId, but I'm unable to figure out how to get the other.

**JSON response:**

```js
"Data":{"DebtorId":1,"Data":
[{"Id":"Felt01","Label":"Navn","Value":"Testmedlem"},
{"Id":"Felt14","Label":"Bemærkninger","Value":""},
{"Id":"Felt15","Label":"Oprettet den","Value":null},
{"Id":"Felt16","Label":"Sidst rettet","Value":"2015-12-04T22:56:36"},
{"Id":"Felt23","Label":"Udmeldt","Value":null},
{"Id":"Felt12","Label":"Note","Value":""},
{"Id":"Felt02","Label":"Adresse 1","Value":"Adresse 1"},
{"Id":"Felt03","Label":"Postnr","Value":""},
{"Id":"Felt04","Label":"Bynavn","Value":""},
{"Id":"Felt05","Label":"Mobiltelefon","Value":""},
{"Id":"Felt06","Label":"Adresse 2","Value":""},
{"Id":"Felt07","Label":"Telefon","Value":""},
{"Id":"Felt08","Label":"Efternavn","Value":""},
{"Id":"Felt10","Label":"Email","Value":""},
{"Id":"Felt24","Label":"Aktiv","Value":false},
{"Id":"Felt09","Label":"Grupper og roller","Value":[]},
{"Id":"Felt11","Label":"Medlemskontingent","Value":0},
{"Id":"Felt13","Label":"Medarbejdernr","Value":""},
{"Id":"Felt17","Label":"Ansættelsessted","Value":{"Id":0,"Code":null,"Value":null}},
{"Id":"Felt18","Label":"Land","Value":""},
{"Id":"Felt19","Label":"Medlemsnummer","Value":1},
{"Id":"Felt20","Label":"Donation","Value":0.0},
{"Id":"Felt21","Label":"WebID","Value":0}]},
"WinkasErrorCode":0,"WinKasStatus":0,"WinKasStatusString":"Okay",
"WinKasMessage":null,"ApiVersion":"1.1.888.91",
"ResponseDateTime":"2015-12-04T23:23:19"
```

**Classic ASP:**

```vb
Response.Write "<p>Result (single):" & requestBody.data("DebtorId").item(phonenr) & "</p>"
  For Each phonenr In requestBody.Data
    Set this = requestBody.data("Data").item(Id)
    Response.Write _
    this.item("type") & ": " & _
    this.item("number") & "<br>"
  Next
```

Comment: There are quite a few questions on SO about using JSON with Classic ASP.  I find it's easier to use (server side) Javascript rather than VBScript as your scripting language rather than classes like ASPJSON, see my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538292/asp-json-object-not-a-collection/30546374#30546374

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do what you want. 
Please note that I enclosed your JSON in curly braces to create an actual JSON object. Also, you will have to add some code to differentiate between the different forms that the value node can take ("", [], {})

```
dim oJSON
Set oJSON = New aspJSON
dim jsonText
call InitJsonText

dim key
dim this

'Load JSON string
oJSON.loadJSON(jsonText)

Response.Write( oJSON.data("Data").item("DebtorId"))

dim dataNode : set dataNode = oJSON.data("Data").item("Data")
' List data array entries
For Each key In dataNode
   Set this  = dataNode.item(key)
   response.Write("key: " & key & ":" & this.item("Id") &  " - "  & this.item("Label") & "<br/>")
Next


sub InitJsonText
  jsonText = _
    "{ " & vbNewLine  & _
    "   ""Data"":{ " & vbNewLine  & _
    "      ""DebtorId"":1, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "      ""Data"":[ " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt01"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Navn"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":""Testmedlem"" " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt14"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Bemærkninger"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":"""" " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt15"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Oprettet den"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":null " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt16"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Sidst rettet"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":""2015-12-04T22:56:36"" " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt23"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Udmeldt"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":null " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt12"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Note"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":"""" " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt02"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Adresse 1"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":""Adresse 1"" " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt03"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Postnr"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":"""" " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt04"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Bynavn"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":"""" " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt05"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Mobiltelefon"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":"""" " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt06"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Adresse 2"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":"""" " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt07"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Telefon"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":"""" " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt08"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Efternavn"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":"""" " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt10"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Email"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":"""" " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt24"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Aktiv"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":false " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt09"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Grupper og roller"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":[ " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ] " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt11"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Medlemskontingent"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":0 " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt13"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Medarbejdernr"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":"""" " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt17"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Ansættelsessted"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":{ " & vbNewLine  & _
    "               ""Id"":0, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "               ""Code"":null, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "               ""Value"":null " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            } " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt18"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Land"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":"""" " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt19"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Medlemsnummer"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":1 " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt20"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""Donation"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":0.0 " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         { " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Id"":""Felt21"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Label"":""WebID"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "            ""Value"":0 " & vbNewLine  & _
    "         } " & vbNewLine  & _
    "      ] " & vbNewLine  & _
    "   }, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "   ""WinkasErrorCode"":0, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "   ""WinKasStatus"":0, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "   ""WinKasStatusString"":""Okay"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "   ""WinKasMessage"":null, " & vbNewLine  & _
    "   ""ApiVersion"":""1.1.888.91"", " & vbNewLine  & _
    "   ""ResponseDateTime"":""2015-12-04T23:23:19"" " & vbNewLine  & _
    "} "
end sub
```