# Classic ASP, How to select some items from a json output?

Tags: json, asp-classic

```
<%
SUB makeFeed(url)

Set xml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

xml.Open "GET", url, False

xml.setRequestHeader "Client-ID", "*removed*"

xml.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/vnd.twitchtv.v4+json"

xml.Send

sXml = xml.responseText

Response.write sXML

Set xml = Nothing

Set sXml = Nothing

end sub

makeFeed("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/clips/top?limit=2&game=Overwatch&trending=true")

%>
```

How do I convert the json output so I can select what I want to show on the page instead of the entire thing?

Doc from the api: 
https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/guides/clips-discovery/

Comment: Oh sorry, new to this site, that was a mistake.

Comment: I have fixed it for you. Please be careful tagging in the future, as properly tagging your question helps it get seen by the correct people who might have a solution for you.

Comment: ASP Classic (VBScript) does not have any native way of parsing JSON (as it predates it by quite a few years).  What you need to either use an external library or JScript to parse it.  There are various ones around, just search for "asp classic json"

Comment: I find it's much easier to deal with json on the server side if you use JavaScript instead of VBscript...

Comment: I second @TimWilliams on this.  I've given an example in this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538292/asp-json-object-not-a-collection/30546374#30546374

Comment: Try looking at https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON