# Looping though JSON classic ASP

Tags: json, asp-classic

I am trying to use aspJSON1.17.asp to get data from an JSON file that I am pulling back. ASPJson Site is located here now.
http://web.archive.org/web/20160109181310/http://aspjson.com/

The structure of the file is as follows. NOTE: I have truncated here for readability

```
{
          "@odata.context": "http://trestle.corelogic.com/odata/$metadata#Property/CoreLogic.DataStandard.RESO.DD_1_5.Property",
          "value": [
            {
              "@odata.type": "#CoreLogic.DataStandard.RESO.DD_1_5.Property",
              "AboveGradeFinishedArea": null,
              "AboveGradeFinishedAreaSource": null,
              "AboveGradeFinishedAreaUnits": null,
              "AccessCode": null,
              "AccessibilityFeatures": null,
              "AdditionalParcelsDescription": null,
              "AdditionalParcelsYN": null,
              "AnchorsCoTenants": null,
              "Appliances": null,
              "ApprovalStatus": null,
              "ArchitecturalStyle": null,
              "AssociationAmenities": null,
              "AssociationFee": null,
              "AssociationFee2": null,
              "AssociationFee2Frequency": null,
              "AssociationFeeFrequency": null,
              "AssociationFeeIncludes": null,
              "AssociationName": null,
              "AssociationName2": null,
              "AssociationPhone": null,
              "AssociationPhone2": null,
              "AssociationYN": null,
              "AttachedGarageYN": null,
              "AvailabilityDate": null,
              "Basement": null,
              "BathroomsFull": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried the following where pagereturn is the JSON formatted string I am getting back from the API. I am trying to loop though this collection but I cannot get it to work. I keep getting an Object not a collection error.

Here is what I have tried

```
Set oJSON = New aspJSON
'Load JSON string
oJSON.loadJSON(pageReturn)

'Loop through collection
For Each record In oJSON.data("Property")
    Set this = oJSON.data("Property").item(record)
    Response.Write _
    this.item("bathroomsFull") & "<br> "
Next
```

AND

```
'Loop through collection
For Each record In oJSON.data("bathroomsFull")
    Set this = oJSON.data("bathroomsFull").item(record)
    Response.Write _
    this.item("bathroomsFull") & "<br> "
Next
```

This did not give me an error but I got an empty sting

```
Response.Write "BathRooms"& oJSON.data("bathroomsFull") & "<br>"
```

Based on the above I would have thought that I would get "10"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to follow the structure of the json. In this case object -> property -> collection -> object. Had a similar question a while ago - https://stackoverflow.com/a/30574537/692942.

Comment: @Lankymart thanks for the response. Based on your response I would have thought I would get something from this 

Response.Write "BathRooms"& oJSON.data("bathroomsFull") & "<br>" but It does not return anything.  Any suggestions

Comment: Why would that work? `oJSON.data()` is expecting the first level of the structure which is the anonymous object with a property called `value`, there is no `bathroomsFull` property at that level, does that make sence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s just a case of understanding the structure of the json, then you can recreate the steps needed to pull the value in code.

The structure appears to be;

```
object
  property
    collection
      object
        property
```

So the code should be something like this;

```vb
Set oJSON = New aspJSON
'Load JSON string
oJSON.loadJSON(pageReturn)

'Loop through collection
For Each record In oJSON.data("value")
  'Object Reference within the Array.
  Set this = oJSON.data("value").item(record)
  'Use the Object Reference to access it's properties.
  Response.Write this.item("BathroomsFull") & "<br> "
Next
```

Comment: @lankymark Thanks for the suggestion however, when I run that it still returns nothing. The actual output was 
<br> <br> <br> <br>  which tells me that they are looping though the records but still not accessing the values. I see there are 4 objects returned when I use a JSON viewer.

Comment: @rob you will also need the correct case for the property, i’ve updated my example. Unfortunately i’m doung this from my mobile so not in a position to test it’s accuracy, but it should be close. If you are still struggling, try debugging at each level until you get what you are expecting.

Comment: @Lankymark Thanks for the help. I was able to get the values back. I appreciate. it

Comment: @Rob glad to help.