# How to get values from json string with aspJSON.asp?

Tags: json, vbscript, asp-classic

I have this JSON and no matter what I try I can´t get any values from it. I don´t know what Im missing?

This is the json string.

```
 {
        "groups": [{
            "name": "Credit Card",
            "types": ["mc", "visa", "amex"]
        }],
        "paymentMethods": [{
            "brands": ["mc", "visa", "amex"],
            "details": [{
                "key": "encryptedCardNumber",
                "type": "cardToken"
            }, {
                "key": "encryptedSecurityCode",
                "type": "cardToken"
            }, {
                "key": "encryptedExpiryMonth",
                "type": "cardToken"
            }, {
                "key": "encryptedExpiryYear",
                "type": "cardToken"
            }, {
                "key": "holderName",
                "optional": true,
                "type": "text"
            }],
            "name": "Card",
            "type": "scheme"
        }, {
            "name": "FÃ¥ fÃ¶rst. Betala sen med Klarna.",
            "supportsRecurring": true,
            "type": "klarna"
        }, {
            "name": "Trustly",
            "supportsRecurring": true,
            "type": "trustly"
        }, {
            "name": "Swish",
            "supportsRecurring": true,
            "type": "swish"
        }, {
            "name": "Paysafecard",
            "supportsRecurring": true,
            "type": "paysafecard"
        }, {
            "name": "Dela upp med Klarna.",
            "supportsRecurring": true,
            "type": "klarna_account"
        }, {
            "name": "Pay now with Klarna.",
            "supportsRecurring": true,
            "type": "klarna_paynow"
        }]
    }
```

And then I try to get one single value(the "Credit Card") and also loop through all the paymetsMethods.details.key values and then loop all the last "name".

```
<!--#include file="aspJSON1.17.asp" -->
        jsonstring = CStr(objXmlHttp.ResponseText)
        'response.write "---"&jsonstring &"---"
        Set oJSON = New aspJSON
        oJSON.loadJSON(jsonstring)
        
        groupsname=oJSON.data("groups").item("name")
        response.write groupsname
        
        For Each x In oJSON.data("paymentMethods").item("details")
        paymentMethods=oJSON.data("paymentMethods").item("details").item("key")
        response.write paymentMethods
        NEXT
        
        For Each x In oJSON.data("name")
        thename=oJSON.data.item("name")
        response.write thename
        NEXT
```

Im clearly missing something, but what?

Comment: I just found your question looking for newly created tags and wonder why we need two new asp-tags, considering [there are already about 120 of them](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=117&tab=name). Is it about asp.net?

Comment: Problem with the tag [tag:aspjson] is it's too ambiguous as there are other libraries called [aspJSON](https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON) as opposed to [this one](https://www.aspjson.com/) which I think the OP is using.

Comment: What happens, does it print nothing does it error... what?

Comment: You need to look at the duplicate the issue here is you need to first loop through `paymentMethods` before you can then get at each `details` collection. The code needs a nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

When parsing JSON if you come across a collection (i.e. an Array) you have to iterate through it before trying to retrieve values deeper in the JSON structure.

In this case, to get to the `key` property you have to iterate through two collections.

1. `paymentMethods`
2. `details`

So this `For` loop;

```vb
For Each x In oJSON.data("paymentMethods").item("details")
paymentMethods=oJSON.data("paymentMethods").item("details").item("key")
response.write paymentMethods
NEXT
```

Should look more like;

```vb
Dim paymentMethod, paymentMethodsItem, details, detailsItem
For Each paymentMethodsItem In oJSON.data("paymentMethods")
    Set paymentMethod = oJSON.data("paymentMethods").item(paymentMethodsItem)
    For Each detailsItem In paymentMethod.data("details")
        Set details = paymentMethod.data("details").item(detailsItem)
        Call Response.Write(details.item("key"))
    Next
Next
```

<sup><sup>#</sup>*Code provided untested*</sup>

---

#### Useful Links

- [Looping though JSON classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48271545/692942)
- [ASP JSON: Object not a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30574537/692942)