# How to loop over collection with AspJson?

Tags: json, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a json string:

```
[{"file":"78jsyhpg9mtf.jpg"},{"file":"imqk2680ra4p.jpg"}]
```

that doesn't have primary object name. It is accessible via data(0)...

But how do I iterate with for next loop over all elements in collection?

Using

```
Set oJSON = New aspJSON for each file in oJSON.data() ... next
```

obviously doesn't work. And I can not use oJSON.data("name") as the collection does not have primary data object.

I am using this script: https://github.com/gerritvankuipers/aspjson/blob/master/aspJSON1.19.asp

Comment: `for each x in oJSON.data : Response.write oJSON.data(x).item("file") & "<br/>" : next`

Comment: This actually works, I've tried everything else I guess... except this... Thank you so much. If you would write this in answer I will accept it.

Comment: It's okay. Glad to help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP JSON: Object not a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538292/asp-json-object-not-a-collection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the nodes of the object like this

```
For Each obj in oJSON.data
  Response.Write( oJSON.data(obj).item("file") )
Next
```