# How to validate Google Recaptcha 2.0 server side in ASP Classic?

Tags: asp-classic, recaptcha

I need help to implement the answer Google Recaptcha 2.0.

I've tried a few ways to recover the response after sending the form but not consigui get the answer True.

Follows the example I'm trying:

```
<%@LANGUAGE=VBSCRIPT%>
<%
    Option Explicit
%>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    </head>

    <body>
<%
    If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then
        Dim recaptcha_secret, sendstring, objXML
        ' Secret key
        recaptcha_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxsec"

        sendstring = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" & recaptcha_secret & "&response=" & Request.form("g-recaptcha-response")

        Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        objXML.Open "GET", sendstring, False

        objXML.Send

        Response.write "<br><h3>Response: " & objXML.responseText & "</h3><br>"



  Set objXML = Nothing

  END If

%>

        <form method="post" action="">
            <!-- Site key -->
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxx"></div>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Try">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I implement a way to check that Recaptcha were marked?

Comment: Why do you need the responses, they are sent to Google and processed you don’t need to know what was asked during the recaptcha just that they past it.

Comment: There in lies the problem...

Comment: i need to check the response if its true or false with if conditions

Comment: Get on and do it then, you already have the `responseText` so check it.

Comment: So your actual question is "How do you parse JSON in Classic ASP?". Stick that in Google and you will get a wealth of answers from this very site, no need for duplicates.

Comment: As a start, check out the *"Useful Links"* section in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38188074/692942).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally found it after so many search i found it 
first i use this asp class https://github.com/zhennanzhuce/js/blob/master/js/ueditor/1.4.3/asp/ASPJson.class.asp
then to validate the response i use this

```
    result = (objXML.responseText)

    Set oJSON = New aspJSON
    oJSON.loadJSON(result)

    Set objXML = Nothing

    success = oJSON.data("success")
    if success = "True" then

        action = "go to next page"

    else

        action = ""


    end if
```

now the used code is :

```
<%@LANGUAGE=VBSCRIPT%>
<%
Option Explicit
%>
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- #include file="aspJSON.asp"-->

<%
If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then
    Dim recaptcha_secret, sendstring, objXML
    ' Secret key
    recaptcha_secret = "XXXCCCXXXX"

    sendstring = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit&secret=" & recaptcha_secret & "&response=" & Request.form("g-recaptcha-response")

    Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objXML.Open "GET", sendstring, False

    objXML.Send
    dim result, oJSON, success, action, errorCapatcha, errorMsg 

    result = (objXML.responseText)

    Set oJSON = New aspJSON
    oJSON.loadJSON(result)

    Set objXML = Nothing

    success = oJSON.data("success")
    if success = "True" then

        action = "go to next page"

    else

        action = "do nothing"


    end if

 END If

%>

    <form method="post" action="">
        <!-- Site key -->
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXX"></div>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Try">
    </form>
</body>
```

Many Thanks to Lankymart, Leonardo Duarte

Comment: The link you mention is not the library you have used, it's more likely [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20160620154733/http://www.aspjson.com:80/) which went offline in June 2016 but who's code can still be found if you look hard enough *(linked from archive.org)*. The linked library doesn't have a `loadJSON()` method.

Comment: My point is the link in your answer is not the file you are using. That library doesn't have a `loadJSON()` method, you've linked the wrong URL by accident.

Comment: I don’t know how to be any clearer. The code in your answer and the library you link in the answer are different. Does the library https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON have a `loadJSON()` method like you use in your code?, the answer is no. So how can you be using it unless the code in your answer doesn’t reflect what you “actually” used?

Comment: i will check the code again and i will give you the sure tomorrow

Comment: @Lankymrt
sorry for delay i check the file now
the correct file at https://github.com/zhennanzhuce/js/blob/master/js/ueditor/1.4.3/asp/ASPJson.class.asp

Answer (score 0):

First download json.asp https://github.com/tugrul/aspjson

insert in page

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server" src="json2.asp"></script>
```

in return do so

```
If success(objXML.responseText) = True Then

Response.write "success"

Elseif success(objXML.responseText) = False Then

Response.write "failure"

End If
```

call the function to get the json

```
Function success(result)

Set motor = JSON.parse(result)      

success = motor.success

Set motor = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: `Set motor`, nice c+p code. Also, just use `#include` to include the JSON asp script.

Comment: i use this link ( https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON)
'result = (objXML.responseText)

  Set oJSON = New aspJSON
  oJSON.loadJSON(result)

    Set objXML = Nothing
       
     success = oJSON.data("success")
     if success = "True" then
     
   action = "Go"

    else

   action = "Nothing"
  
    Response.write("error with Capatcha<BR>")
   
    end if
'

Thanks for you help

Comment: please check my response and tell me if you see any thing better

Comment: Thanks for help but i get some error that time 
i think there is some asp functions not working on server side
i use the top code and working very well for me

Answer (score -2):

There is a better way and stand alone captcha for ASP instead google captcha. You don't need to add JSON function.
Here is the code:

On your submit page, add:

```
   Type the number bellow:<br>
   <input type=text name="captchacode" value="" size=5 maxlength=5><br/>
   <img id="imgCaptcha" src="captcha.asp" /><br />
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="RefreshImage('imgCaptcha')">Refresh</a><br/>
<script language="Javascript">
function RefreshImage(valImageId) {
    var objImage = document.images[valImageId];
    if (objImage == undefined) {
        return;
    }
    var now = new Date();
    objImage.src = objImage.src.split('?')[0] + '?x=' + now.toUTCString();
}
</script>
```

Insert the function bellow to your asp file:

```
'*******************************************************
function TestCaptcha(byval valSession, byval valCaptcha)
'*******************************************************
dim tmpSession
valSession = Trim(valSession)
valCaptcha = Trim(valCaptcha)
if (valSession = vbNullString) or (valCaptcha = vbNullString) then
   TestCaptcha = false
else
   tmpSession = valSession
   valSession = Trim(Session(valSession))
   Session(tmpSession) = vbNullString
   if valSession = vbNullString then
      TestCaptcha = false
   else
      valCaptcha = Replace(valCaptcha,"i","I")
      if StrComp(valSession,valCaptcha,1) = 0 then
         TestCaptcha = true
      else
         TestCaptcha = false
      end if
   end if
end if
end function
```

Save the code bellow to captcha.asp:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%>
<%
'ASP Security Image Generator v4.0 - 13/July/2008
'Generate images to make a CAPTCHA test
'© 2006-2007 Emir Tüzül. All rights reserved.
'http://www.tipstricks.org

'This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
'modify it under the terms of the Common Public License
'as published by the Open Source Initiative OSI; either version 1.0
'of the License, or any later version.

'This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
'but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
'MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
'Common Public License for more details.

'*[null pixel]Numbers[repeat count], #[text]Numbers[repeat count], &[row reference]number[referenced row index]
'First row [font height, chars...]
'Following rows [char width, pixel maps...]
FontMap = Array(_
split("13,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9",",") ,_
split("14,*5#4*5,*4#6*4,&2,&2,*3#3*2#3*3,&5,*2#4*2#4*2,*2#3*4#3*2,*2#10*2,*1#12*1,*1#3*6#3*1,&11,#3*8#3",",") ,_
split("11,#8*3,#10*1,#3*4#3*1,&3,&3,&1,&2,#3*4#4,#3*5#3,&9,&8,&2,#9*2",",") ,_
split("11,*4#6*1,*2#9,*1#4*4#2,*1#3*6#1,#3*8,&5,&5,&5,&5,&4,&3,&2,&1",",") ,_
split("12,#8*4,#10*2,#3*4#4*1,#3*5#3*1,#3*6#3,&5,&5,&5,&5,&4,&3,&2,&1",",") ,_
split("9,#9,&1,#3*6,&3,&3,#8*1,&6,&3,&3,&3,&3,&1,&1",",") ,_
split("9,#9,&1,#3*6,&3,&3,&1,&1,&3,&3,&3,&3,&3,&3",",") ,_
split("13,*4#7,*2#11,*1#4*5#3,*1#3*8#1,#3,#3,#3*4#6,&7,#3*7#3,*1#3*6#3,*1#5*4#3,&2,&1",",") ,_
split("11,#3*5#3,&1,&1,&1,&1,#11,&6,&1,&1,&1,&1,&1,&1",",") ,_
split("7,#7,#7,*2#3,&3,&3,&3,&3,&3,&3,&3,&3,&1,&1",",") ,_
split("8,*2#6,&1,*5#3,&3,&3,&3,&3,&3,&3,&3,*4#4,#7,#6",",") ,_
split("12,#3*5#4,#3*4#4,#3*3#4,#3*2#4,#3*2#3,#3*1#3,#7,#8,&5,#3*3#3,#3*4#3,#3*5#3,&1",",") ,_
split("9,#3,#3,#3,#3,#3,#3,#3,#3,#3,#3,#3,#9,#9",",") ,_
split("13,#3*7#3,#4*5#4,&2,#5*3#5,&4,#6*1#6,#3*1#2*1#2*1#3,#3*1#5*1#3,#3*2#3*2#3,&9,#3*7#3,&11,&11",",") ,_
split("11,#4*4#3,#5*3#3,&2,#6*2#3,&4,#3*1#3*1#3,&6,#3*2#6,&8,#3*3#5,&10,#3*4#4,#3*5#3",",") ,_
split("13,*4#5,*2#9,*1#4*3#4,*1#3*5#3,#3*7#3,&5,&5,&5,&5,&4,&3,&2,&1",",") ,_
split("10,#8,#9,#3*3#4,#3*4#3,&4,&4,&3,&2,#7,#3,#3,#3,#3",",") ,_
split("13,*3#6,*2#8,*1#3*4#3,*1#2*6#2,#2*8#2,&5,&5,#2*4#1*3#2,#2*4#2*2#2,*1#2*4#4,&3,*2#10,*3#6*2#2",",") ,_
split("12,#8,#9,#3*4#3,&3,&3,#3*3#4,&2,&1,#3*2#4,#3*3#3,&3,#3*4#4,#3*5#4",",") ,_
split("11,*3#6,*1#9,#4*4#2,#3*6#1,#4,#8,&2,*3#8,*7#4,#1*7#3,#3*4#4,#10,*1#7",",") ,_
split("11,#11,&1,*4#3,&3,&3,&3,&3,&3,&3,&3,&3,&3,&3,&3",",") ,_
split("11,#3*5#3,&1,&1,&1,&1,&1,&1,&1,&1,&1,#4*3#4,*1#9,*3#5",",") ,_
split("14,#3*8#3,*1#3*6#3,&2,*1#3*5#4,*2#3*4#3,&5,*3#3*2#3,&7,&7,*4#6,&10,&10,*5#4",",") ,_
split("17,#3*4#3*4#3,&1,#3*3#5*3#3,*1#3*2#2*1#2*2#3,&4,*1#3*1#3*1#3*1#3,&6,*1#3*1#2*3#2*1#3,&8,*2#5*3#5,&10,*2#4*5#4,&12",",") ,_
split("14,#4*6#4,*1#4*4#4,*2#4*2#4,*3#3*2#3,*3#8,*4#6,*5#4,&6,&5,&4,&3,&2,&1",",") ,_
split("13,#4*5#4,*1#3*5#3,*2#3*3#3,*2#4*1#4,*3#3*1#3,*3#7,*4#5,*5#3,&8,&8,&8,&8,&8",",") ,_
split("10,#10,&1,*6#4,*5#4,*5#3,*4#3,*3#4,*3#3,*2#3,*1#4,#4,&1,&1",",") ,_
split("10,*3#4*3,*1#8*1,*1#3*2#3*1,#3*4#3,&4,&4,&4,&4,&4,&4,&3,&2,&1",",") ,_
split("9,*3#3*3,&1,#6*3,&3,*3#3*3,&5,&5,&5,&5,&5,&5,#9,&12",",") ,_
split("10,*1#6*3,#8*2,#2*3#4*1,#1*5#3*1,*6#3*1,&5,*5#3*2,*4#4*2,*3#4*3,*2#4*4,*1#4*5,#10,&12",",") ,_
split("11,*1#8*2,#10*1,#3*5#3,#1*7#3,*7#3*1,*3#6*2,*3#7*1,*7#4,*8#3,&4,#3*4#4,&2,*1#7*3",",") ,_
split("12,*6#4*2,*5#5*2,&2,*4#2*1#3*2,*3#3*1#3*2,*2#3*2#3*2,*1#3*3#3*2,#3*4#3*2,#12,&9,*7#3*2,&11,&11",",") ,_
split("11,*1#10,&1,*1#3*7,&3,*1#8*2,*1#9*1,*7#4,*8#3,&8,#1*7#3,#3*4#3*1,#10*1,*1#7*3",",") ,_
split("11,*4#6*1,*2#8*1,*1#4*6,*1#3*7,#3*1#5*2,#10*1,#3*4#4,#3*5#3,&8,&8,*1#3*3#3*1,*1#9*1,*3#5*3",",") ,_
split("11,#11,&1,*7#4,*7#3*1,*6#4*1,*6#3*2,*5#3*3,*4#4*3,*4#3*4,*3#4*4,*3#3*5,*2#3*6,*1#4*6",",") ,_
split("11,*2#7*2,*1#9*1,#3*4#4,#3*5#3,#4*3#3*1,*1#8*2,&1,*1#3*1#5*1,&4,&4,#4*3#4,&2,*2#6*3",",") ,_
split("11,*3#5*3,*1#9*1,*1#3*3#3*1,#3*5#3,&4,&4,#4*4#3,*1#10,*2#5*1#3,*7#3*1,*6#4*1,*1#8*2,*1#6*4",",") _
)'Previous row must end with _

'#Begin ColorMap
const BmpColorMap = "dffeff000c851700eceeee006c363600da644a00"

ColorMap = Array(_
split("00,01,01,03",",") ,_
split("02,03,03,01",",") ,_
split("00,04,04,02",",") _
)'End ColorMap

'#Auto calculated variables
dim ImageWidth, ImageHeight, arrTextWidth(), TextHeight, LeftMargin, arrTopMargin(), CursorPos
dim BmpEndLine, BColor, TColor, NColor
dim i, j, k, x, y

'#Editable consts and variables
dim Bitmap(40,200) '[Height,Width]
const CodeLength = 5 'Secure code length (Max:8)
const CodeType = 0 '0[Random numbers], 1[Random chars and numbers], 2[Fake word]
const CharTracking = 35 'Set the tracking between two characters
const RndTopMargin = true 'Randomize top margin every character
const NoiseEffect = 0 '0[none], 1[sketch], 2[random foreground lines], 3[random background lines], 4[1 and 3 (Recommed maximum NoiseLine=4)]
const NoiseLine = 3 'Low values make easy OCR, high values decrease readability
const MinLineLength = 6 'Minimum noise line length
const SessionName = "ASPCAPTCHA" 'Where store your secure code

'#Subroutines and functions
'*****************************
function CreateGUID(valLength)
'*****************************
if CodeType = 1 then
   strValid = "A0B1C2D3E4F5G6H7I8J9K8L7M6N5O4P3Q2R1S0T1U2V3W4X5Y6Z7"
else
   strValid = "0516273849"
end if
tmpGUID = vbNullString
tmpChr = vbNullString
Randomize(Timer)
for cGUID=1 to valLength
    do
      tmpChr = Mid(strValid, Int(Rnd(1) * Len(strValid)) + 1, 1)
    loop while CStr(tmpChr) = CStr(Right(tmpGUID,1))
    tmpGUID = tmpGUID & tmpChr
Next
CreateGUID = tmpGUID
end function

'***************************
function FakeWord(valLength)
'***************************
arrChars = Array("AEIOU", "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ")
cVowel = 0
cConsonant = 0
tmpWord = vbNullString
Randomize(Timer)
for cWord=1 to valLength
    if (cWord=2) or ((valLength > 1) and (cWord = valLength)) then
        ixChars = 1-ixChars
    elseif (cVowel < 2) and (cConsonant < 2) then
        ixChars = Int(Rnd(1) * 2)
    elseif (cVowel < 2) then
        ixChars = 0
    elseif (cConsonant < 2) then
        ixChars = 1
    end if
    Pattern = arrChars(ixChars)
    tmpWord = tmpWord & Mid(Pattern, Int(Rnd(1) * Len(Pattern)) + 1, 1)
    if ixChars = 0 then
        cVowel = cVowel + 1
        cConsonant = 0
    else
        cVowel = 0
        cConsonant = cConsonant + 1
    end if
next
FakeWord = tmpWord
end function

'**********************************
function RndInterval(valMin,valMax)
'**********************************
Randomize(Timer)
RndInterval = Int(((valMax - valMin + 1) * Rnd()) + valMin)
end function

'**************************
function GetCharMap(valChr)
'**************************
dim i, j
j = 0
for i=1 to UBound(FontMap(0))
    if CStr(FontMap(0)(i)) = CStr(valChr) then
       j = i
      exit for
    end if
next
if j > 0 then
   GetCharMap = FontMap(j)
else
   GetCharMap = Array(0)
end if
end function

'************************************************
sub WriteCanvas(byval valChr, byval valTopMargin)
'************************************************
dim i, j, k, curPos, tmpChr, arrChrMap, strPixMap, drawPixel, pixRepeat

'find char map
arrChrMap = GetCharMap(valChr)
if UBound(arrChrMap) < 1 then
   exit sub
end if
for i=1 to UBound(arrChrMap)
   'get pixel map active line
    strPixMap = arrChrMap(i)
    if Left(strPixMap,1) = "&" then
       j = Mid(strPixMap,2)
       if (IsNumeric(j) = true) then
          strPixMap = arrChrMap(CInt(j))
       else
          strPixMap = vbNullString
       end if
    end if
    strPixMap = Trim(strPixMap)

    'drawing pixel
    curPos = CursorPos
    drawPixel = false
    pixRepeat = vbNullString
    for j=1 to Len(strPixMap)
        tmpChr = Mid(strPixMap,j,1)
        if (IsNumeric(tmpChr) = true) and (j < Len(strPixMap)) then
           pixRepeat = pixRepeat & tmpChr
        else
           'end pixel map?
           if IsNumeric(tmpChr) = true then
              pixRepeat = pixRepeat & tmpChr
           end if
           'draw pixel
           if (drawPixel = true) and (IsNumeric(pixRepeat) = true) then
              for k=1 to CInt(pixRepeat)
                  curPos = curPos + 1
                  Bitmap((valTopMargin + i),curPos) = TColor
              next
           elseif IsNumeric(pixRepeat) = true then
              curPos = curPos + CInt(pixRepeat)
           end if

           'what is new command?
           if tmpChr = "#" then
              drawPixel = true
           else
              drawPixel = false
           end if
           pixRepeat = vbNullString
        end if
    next
next
end sub

'*******************************
sub PrepareBitmap(valSecureCode)
'*******************************
dim i, j
'image dimensions
ImageWidth = UBound(Bitmap,2)
ImageHeight = UBound(Bitmap,1)

'char and text width
redim arrTextWidth(CodeLength)
arrTextWidth(0) = 0
for i=1 to CodeLength
    arrTextWidth(i) = CInt(GetCharMap(Mid(secureCode,i,1))(0))
    arrTextWidth(0) = arrTextWidth(0) + arrTextWidth(i)
next
arrTextWidth(0) = arrTextWidth(0) + ((CodeLength - 1) * CharTracking)

'text height
TextHeight = CInt(FontMap(0)(0))

'left margin
LeftMargin = Round((ImageWidth - arrTextWidth(0)) / 2)

'top margin
redim arrTopMargin(CodeLength)
arrTopMargin(0) = Round((ImageHeight - TextHeight) / 2)
if RndTopMargin = true then
    for i=1 to CodeLength
        arrTopMargin(i) = RndInterval(Int(arrTopMargin(0) / 2),(arrTopMargin(0) + Round(arrTopMargin(0) / 2)))
    next
else
    for i=1 to CodeLength
        arrTopMargin(i) = arrTopMargin(0)
    next
end if

'color selection
i = RndInterval(0,UBound(ColorMap))
BColor = ColorMap(i)(0)
NColor = ColorMap(i)(1)
TColor = ColorMap(i)(2)

'Apply background effect
if NoiseEffect = 3 then
    AddNoise()
end if

'write text
for i=1 to CodeLength
    'calculate cursor pos
    CursorPos = 0
    for j=(i-1) to 1 step -1
        CursorPos = CursorPos + arrTextWidth(j) + CharTracking
    next
    CursorPos = LeftMargin + CursorPos

    'write active char
    WriteCanvas Mid(secureCode,i,1),arrTopMargin(i)
next
end sub

'***********************************
sub DrawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1, valClr)
'***********************************
'Reference from Donald Hearn and M. Pauline Baker, Computer Graphics C Version
dim m, b, dx, dy
if (NoiseEffect = 4) and (Bitmap(y0,x0) = TColor) then
    clrNoise = vbNullString
else
    clrNoise = valClr
end if
Bitmap(y0,x0) = clrNoise

dx = x1 - x0
dy = y1 - y0
if Abs(dx) > Abs(dy) then
    m = (dy / dx)
    b = y0 - (m * x0)
    if dx < 0 then
        dx = -1
    else
        dx = 1
    end if

    do while x0 <> x1
        x0 = x0 + dx
        if (NoiseEffect = 4) and (Bitmap(Round((m * x0) + b),x0) = TColor) then
            clrNoise = vbNullString
        else
            clrNoise = valClr
        end if
        Bitmap(Round((m * x0) + b),x0) = clrNoise
    loop
elseif dy <> 0 then
    m = (dx / dy)
    b = x0 - (m * y0)

    if dy < 0 then
        dy = -1
    else
        dy = 1
    end if

    do while y0 <> y1
        y0 = y0 + dy

        if (NoiseEffect = 4) and (Bitmap(y0,Round((m * y0) + b)) = TColor) then
            clrNoise = vbNullString
        else
            clrNoise = valClr
        end if
        Bitmap(y0,Round((m * y0) + b)) = clrNoise
    loop
end if
end sub

'*************
sub AddNoise()
'*************
dim median, i, j, x0, y0, x1, y1, dx, dy, dxy

if NoiseEffect = 1 then
    clrNoise = vbNullString
else
    clrNoise = NColor
end if

for i=1 to NoiseLine
    x0 = RndInterval(1,ImageWidth)
    y0 = RndInterval(1,ImageHeight)
    x1 = RndInterval(1,ImageWidth)
    y1 = RndInterval(1,ImageHeight)

    'Check minimum line length
    dx = Abs(x1 - x0)
    dy = Abs(y1 - y0)
    median = Round(Sqr((dx * dx) + (dy * dy))/2)
    if median < MinLineLength then
        dxy = MinLineLength - median

        if x1 < x0 then
            dx = -1
        else
            dx = 1
        end if

        if y1 < y0 then
            dy = -1
        else
            dy = 1
        end if

        for j=1 to dxy
            if ((x1 + dx) < 1) or ((x1 + dx) > ImageWidth) or ((y1 + dy) < 1) or ((y1 + dy) > ImageHeight) then
                exit for
            end if
            x1 = x1 + dx
            y1 = y1 + dy
        next
    end if

    'Draw noise line
    DrawLine x0,y0,x1,y1,clrNoise
next
end sub

'*****************************************************************
function FormatHex(byval valHex,byval fixByte,fixDrctn,valReverse)
'*****************************************************************
fixByte = fixByte * 2
tmpLen = Len(valHex)
if fixByte > tmpLen then
    tmpFixHex = String((fixByte - tmpLen),"0")
    if fixDrctn = 1 then
        valHex = valHex & tmpFixHex
    else
        valHex = tmpFixHex & valHex
    end if
end if

if valReverse = true then
    tmpHex = vbNullString
    for cFrmtHex=1 to Len(valHex) step 2
        tmpHex = Mid(valHex,cFrmtHex,2) & tmpHex
    next
    FormatHex = tmpHex
else
    FormatHex = CStr(valHex)
end if
end function

'******************
sub SendHex(valHex)
'******************
for cHex = 1 to Len(valHex) step 2
    Response.BinaryWrite ChrB(CByte("&H" & Mid(valHex,cHex,2)))
next
end sub

'***************
sub SendBitmap()
'***************
if (ImageWidth mod 4) <> 0 then
    BmpEndLine = String((4-(ImageWidth mod 4))*2,"0")
else
    BmpEndLine = vbNullString
end if
BmpInfoHeader = Array("28000000","00000000","00000000","0100","0800","00000000","00000000","120B0000","120B0000","00000000","00000000")
BmpInfoHeader(1) = FormatHex(Hex(ImageWidth),4,0,true)
BmpInfoHeader(2) = FormatHex(Hex(ImageHeight),4,0,true)
BmpInfoHeader(6) = FormatHex(Hex((ImageHeight * ImageWidth) + (ImageHeight * (Len(BmpEndLine) / 2))),4,0,true)
BmpInfoHeader(9) = FormatHex(Hex(Len(BmpColorMap)/8),4,0,true)
BmpInfoHeader(10) = BmpInfoHeader(9)
BmpHeader = Array("424D","00000000","0000","0000","00000000")
BmpHeader(1) = FormatHex(Hex((Len(Join(BmpHeader,"")) / 2) + (Len(Join(BmpInfoHeader,"")) / 2) + (Len(BmpColorMap) / 2) + (ImageHeight * ImageWidth) + (ImageHeight * (Len(BmpEndLine) / 2))),4,0,true)
BmpHeader(4) = FormatHex(Hex((Len(Join(BmpHeader,"")) / 2) + (Len(Join(BmpInfoHeader,"")) / 2) + (Len(BmpColorMap) / 2)),4,0,true)

Response.Clear
Response.Buffer = True
Response.ContentType = "image/bmp"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=captcha.bmp"
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
Response.Expires = -1

SendHex(Join(BmpHeader,""))
SendHex(Join(BmpInfoHeader,""))
SendHex(BmpColorMap)
for y=ImageHeight to 1 step -1
    for x=1 to ImageWidth
        tmpHex = Bitmap(y,x)
        if tmpHex = vbNullString then
            SendHex(BColor)
        else
            SendHex(tmpHex)
        end if
    next
    SendHex(BmpEndLine)
next
Response.Flush
end sub

'#Generate captcha
if CodeType < 2 then
    secureCode = CreateGUID(CodeLength)
else
    secureCode = FakeWord(CodeLength)
end if
Session(SessionName) = secureCode
PrepareBitmap(secureCode)
if (NoiseEffect > 0) and (NoiseEffect <> 3) then
    AddNoise()
end if
SendBitmap()
%>
```

Before process, validate the captcha:

```
<%
if not TestCaptcha("ASPCAPTCHA", request("captchacode")) then
   response.write "Captcha error!"
   response.end
end if
response.write "Captcha OK"
'... process...

%>
```

Comment: This answer is providing a "homemade" captcha system. It is not related to Recaptcha at all.