Classic ASP and json2.js: how to access keys with special characters?
In this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1021848/5280471 it is suggested to use a "language-wrapping" technique to implement JSON parsing by importing a json2.js JavaScript file like so:
<script language="JScript" runat="server" src='path/to/json2.js'></script>

<%

Dim myJSON
myJSON = Request.Form("myJSON") // "[ 1, 2, 3 ]"
Set myJSON = JSON.parse(myJSON) // [1,2,3]
Response.Write(myJSON)          // 1,2,3
Response.Write(myJSON.[0])      // 1
Response.Write(myJSON.[1])      // 2
Response.Write(myJSON.[2])      // 3
%>

Where json2.js can be found at https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js .
The problem rose when I was trying to interpret a google recaptcha return JSON, which is:
{"success":false,"error-codes":["invalid-input-response"]}

So, I can access myJSON.success no problem. Yet I don't know how I could access, from ASP, the error-codes array. Is there any way that could be achieved from ASP, or am I stuck there?
I already tried some random tricks, like calling MyJSON.get("error-codes"), some obvious syntax errors like MyJSON("error-codes"), MyJSON."error-codes" and also hoped for the best, MyJSON.error_codes as well as MyJSON.["error-codes"]. All of them returning their respective exception, code-breaking errors.

I guess you missed the comment on that question that recommends this library? I’ve used it multiple times in the past, makes working with JSON so simple in Classic ASP.

@user692942 I may have not seen that comment you pointed, but I use the aspJson class. The thing is that it doesn't fit very well if I have a script that can be included multiple times (as class definitions can't be within an if statement block to conditionally include it). So the json2 approach was the way to go (or "unfold" the aspjson into a class); furthermore I had issues translating decimals with aspJson which worked just fine with json2.

Sorry I don’t follow, why would you need to include a class definition multiple times? It’s define once than you create instances of it (i.e. Set jsonObj = New JSONobject) that can be used over and over in whatever statement blocks you want.

Suppose I have a helper function to handle strings S, I need it in scripts A, B, but not C. Yet, B is included in both A and C. Thus I would "double-include" S in A and B, but not C and B. Otherwise, I would not include S in B, but then need to include S in C although I don't need it in C, just because C also includes B. And that'd be kind of hard to read while maintaining code or by other developers. So I add an "if" in the S script so its code is only run once. class can't be within if blocks in ASP.

For an actual use case, I have a page form script (C) then the backend submit script (A). Both require a ReCaptcha script (B). The ReCaptcha script (B) and the backend submit page (A) in turn, require a JSON parsing script (S), but the page form script (C) doesn't. I hope this helps clarify the A-B-C-S relation above.

Having the class "added" in the various pages isn’t an issue it’s just a #include you don’t have to use it until you instantiate an object reference from the class. Including a script doesn’t mean it’s executed especially when all it does is define the class that "can" be instantiated. It sounds like you don’t understand how to use #include statements correctly, but you've solved your issue so it’s a mute point.

I am no longer in an environment where I can test this myself, but if memory servers, classic asp allowed special chars as property names, when they were enclosed in brackets.
Have you tried the following syntax?
MyJSON.[error-codes]

You said that you have tried MyJSON.["error-codes"], but since everything inside the brackets is taken literally, the interpreter would look for a property named "error-codes", but there isn't - it's error-codes

your memory served you very well, thanks!

For now, a less-than-optimal solution is to write a helper function, in JS itself, to get the key. For instance, I added this section to my local copy of json2.js file:
    if (typeof JSON.getKey !== "function") {
        JSON.getKey = function (obj, key) {
            return obj[key];
        };
    }

So that I can do:
' here, I mangled the array to have several elements
jsonstr = "{""success"":false,""error-codes"":[""invalid-input-response"", ""element2"", ""element3""]}"

jsonobj = JSON.parse(jsonstr)
response.write("Success is: " & jsonobj.success) ' prints 'false'

errors_array = JSON.getKey(jsonobj, "error-codes")
response.write("Error codes array has: " & errors_array) ' prints 'invalid-input-response,element2,element3

So in the end I needed a JavaScript wrapper to get access to these keys. I'd gladly mark up as answer if somebody suggests a means to elegantly access these keys without wrapping thru javascript.
