# using REST's GET in classic asp

Tags: rest, asp-classic

First of all, I looked on SO already and found a similar question here:

[Calling REST web services from a classic asp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219/calling-rest-web-services-from-a-classic-asp-page)

However, this doesn't solve my problem. I can't find a way to retrieve the correct information provided by my call

```vb
function determineLocationId(identifier)    

    Dim http: Set http = Server.CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    Dim privateKey
    privateKey = "myKey"

    IdentifyUrl = "https://sandbox.uberall.com/api/locations/?identifier=" & identifier & "&private_key=" & privateKey
    With http
      Call .Open("GET", identifyUrl, False)
      Call .Send()
    End With
    If Left(http.Status, 1) = 2 Then
      response.write("updated")
    Else
      'Output error
      Call Response.Write("Server returned: " & http.Status & " " & http.StatusText)
    End If

    response.write(identifyUrl)
    response.end()

    determineLocationId = identifier
end function
```

When I print my `identifyUrl` to the screen and copy & paste it into my browser, I get the correct output. A `json`-formatted object with the information I need.

However, if I print `http.responseBody`, it just yields some chinese chars like this:

> 佄呃偙⁅呈䱍倠䉕䥌⁃ⴢ⼯㍗⽃䐯䑔䠠䵔⁌⸴㄰吠慲獮瑩潩慮⽬䔯≎∠瑨灴⼺眯睷眮⸳牯⽧剔栯浴㑬氯潯敳搮摴㸢਍ℼⴭ䐠瑡楥慮敭›敤慦汵⹴獡⁰㉖〮‰㠰〮⸸〲㈱䠠湡⵳楗汬⁩牆楥敢杲牥ⴠ

What am I doing wrong? The link is definetly the correct one. I also tried to add:

```
Call .SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as it turned out, using `responseBody` wasn't correct. According to the [MSDN-Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106(v=vs.85).aspx) for WinHttpRequest, `responseBody` is retrieving this:

> Retrieves the response entity body as an array of unsigned bytes.

In my case, I had to switch to `reponseText`, which does the correct thing:

> Retrieves the response entity body as text.